# Check start and end date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a date picker one for begin date and end date, i wanted to check to make sure that the user selects dates so that the begin date is before the end date.

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help - this is what i was able to conclude. This is what i added to my post in my controller.cs:

```
        if (viewModel.BeginDate == null)
            viewModel.BeginDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);

        if (viewModel.EndDate == null)
            viewModel.EndDate = DateTime.Today;

        if (viewModel.EndDate < viewModel.BeginDate)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Date Range");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Value))
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No View Selected");
```